# Is there a way to recreate or buy this battery? ICR14500 3.7v

Tags: batteries

I'm trying to repair a soap dispenser: https://www.simplehuman.com/products/foam-sensor-pump

I opened it up and found the battery was damaged, and I wanted to see if I could replace it. Before I opened it up, I was trying to find a product with the wiring already there. I was able to find batteries with the same specs, but nothing with wires already attached.  Will I be able to build a battery myself by like taping wires to either end of a battery? It's unclear what's inside of the blue plastic wrapping

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a cylindrical cell Lithium-Polymer (or Lithium-Ion -- the terms mostly mean the same thing).  You should be able to find something with wires attached, and then splice your connector on (assuming that the connector isn't the problem -- that looks pretty dirty).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't seem to find something with wires attached, it seems to be a pretty ubiquitous battery, but i'm not sure how to query for it with wires attached, any thoughts? i've tried "IR14500 3.7v battery with wires"

Comment: Try searching on "cylindrical cell", then get one with the same dimensions.

Comment: Cut open the plastic around it. From your photo it looks like there may be a BMS under there. There may also be additional markings on the battery itself to reveal what battery chemistry it is based on.

Comment: Any luck? I have the same part and spec numbers and leads on a battery I would like to replace.

Comment: unfortunately i decided to just contact Simplehuman for a new unit, which came with a new battery. because it worked so close to water i was afraid i would botch a job myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just completed the same repair.  Our soap dispenser is almost 6 years old and was not holding its charge very well anymore.   AFAICT Adafruit / & SparkFun don't sell 14500 li-ion batteries, and Amazon, well Amazon...  I ended up buying a 1000mAh (NL1410) 14500 from Nitecore.  Unfortunately the battery dimensions are slightly different.  Note that the "GREAT POWER" battery has its protection circuit on the side (which I think is somewhat unusual).  The soap dispenser housing is designed to fit the old battery (length ~51mm) very snugly, which was a problem because the new battery was 2mm longer.  In addition, the way I attached the wires to the terminals made the new battery another ~1.5mm longer.  Luckily the plastic housing has 2 layers at the top which meant I could easily use a dremel to cut a hole through one layer to let the battery poke through an extra ~3mm ([pic](https://imgur.com/zsY5MFX)).  To make the terminal attachments I used some thin springy metal junked from an old key fob battery holder. This was easy to bend into shape and was pre-tinned for soldering.

Hope this helps anyone else trying to give their Simple Human soap dispenser a little more life.

Comment: thank you for making an account and leaving this amazing information!

Answer (score 4):

The battery seems like a knock-off part since the part number does not match manufacturer's part number. The connector is likely JST PHR-02 and battery seems to be Great Power LIR18650. Adafruit seems to sell an equivalent assembly as #1781 [link](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/adafruit-industries-llc/1781/5054543?s=N4IgTCBcDaIIwFYwA4C0dkGYBsqByAIiALoC%2BQA).

Related link on soldering wires to lithium batteries [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/192793/how-to-solder-wires-on-li-ion-cell-phone-batteries/192827)

Comment: amazing!! thank you! lol i think i'll avoid soldering wires based on steps 1,2 and 3 on that stackexchange post

Comment: I do not think this is an 18650 size cell.  Based on the number on the cell wrapper and the cell capacity, it looks to be a 14500 size cell.  Similar in size to a standard "AA" cell.